# WiFi server in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, networking, dns, npm, wifi

What I want to do is write software in NodeJS to set up a WiFi server similar to those they use at cafeterias (with WPA2 security or something similar) and guests can connect with credentials or for free on my computer. (I am extra curious as to how I can redirect guests to an html page to enter credentials like they do on some places)

Is there a Node plugin(s) that help with something like this? If not, I am looking for advice like this:

- Set up a server on port x and use npm package y and z
- Check out **this** project

**More info:**

I am creating an intranet for academic purposes.

I have written a dns server in my computer in NodeJS that listens on 192.168.2.2:53 for UDP/TCP and successfully resolves domains in my private network.

My computer is a DHCP client of my Router device which provides access to the internet. Devices at home that use my private DNS server will resolve their dns requests to the internet, only if not found in my private dns.